# td-agent buffer violates size & only worker 0 accumulates logs

Tags: fluentd

buffer accumulation goes beyond size limit

> ```
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  867 Oct 13 08:42 worker0/buffer.q594ca13cc1d99db732af807368a5b95a.log
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  105 Oct 13 08:42 worker0/buffer.q594ca13cc1d99db732af807368a5b95a.log.meta
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  867 Oct 13 08:43 worker0/buffer.q594ca175fa6044eca4e6d229bf0b0855.log
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  105 Oct 13 08:43 worker0/buffer.q594ca175fa6044eca4e6d229bf0b0855.log.meta
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  867 Oct 13 08:45 worker0/buffer.q594ca1e86b5ad4ba4c27a47525449337.log
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  105 Oct 13 08:45 worker0/buffer.q594ca1e86b5ad4ba4c27a47525449337.log.meta
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  867 Oct 13 08:46 worker0/buffer.q594ca221a3bfb7c8f8c8615f67ccdabc.log
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  105 Oct 13 08:46 worker0/buffer.q594ca221a3bfb7c8f8c8615f67ccdabc.log.meta
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  867 Oct 13 08:47 worker0/buffer.q594ca25adc02e19e978cd80b3d606ecc.log
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  105 Oct 13 08:47 worker0/buffer.q594ca25adc02e19e978cd80b3d606ecc.log.meta
> ```

The above some logs only.

`du -sh` command gives size 1.7M whereas buffer limit is set to 1M only.

Also, all logs are being collected in worker0 folder.

`td-agent` logs shows only worker #0 processing.

`td-agent` on host 172.168.3.10 is made down to check buffer condition works properly

```
    <system>
      workers 2
      log_level warn
      suppress_repeated_stacktrace true
    </system>

    <worker 0>
      <source>
        @type tcp
        port 8514
        bind 0.0.0.0
        format /(^(?<header>[^\{]+)?(?<message>\{.+type.+\})$)|(^(?<log>[^\{].+))/
         tag system
      </source>
    </worker>

    <source>
      @type syslog
      port 5140
      bind 0.0.0.0
      message_length_limit 6144
      format /(^(?<header>[^\{]+)?(?<message>\{.+type.+\})$)|(^(?<log>[^\{].+))/
      tag syslog
    </source>

      <match fwd.company.logging.product*.172.168.3.10**>
        @type copy
        <store>
          @type forward
          <server>
            host 172.168.3.10
            port 24224
          </server>
          <buffer>
            @type file
            path /appdata/td-agent/log/buffer/forward- 
            buffer/company.logging.product*.172.168.3.10
            flush_mode interval
            flush_interval 10s
            timekey 60
            retry_forever true
            retry_max_interval 5s
            overflow_action drop_oldest_chunk
            total_limit_size 1m
            flush_at_shutdown false
          </buffer>
        </store>
      </match>
```

Buffer shouldn't go beyond it's size and both workers need to process logs buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i got answer myself.

`du -sh` includes sam directory size.
so to avoid confusion , i just added the size of all buffer files.
Still it was more than 1M. 
I did some googling, finally came to know that `td-agent` buffer just takes .log files in account while limiting size. I mean, just add the .log(real buffers) files not .log.meta(info for buffer) then i found the size to be 1M which is correct. 
So, i conclude saying `td-agent` respects buffer size.

For log accumulation on worker0 , since only worker0 is set to listen on port 8514. That's why all logs which were coming on this port were processed by worker0

Please correct me if i'm wrong.